# Advice on primary call-to-action vs. inline call-to-action

Tags: search, ux-designer

I am designing an address search, where the results appear below the search box, there are two questions:

1. Does the box expanding below the search button work or do you think it should end at the width of the search box?

and

2. The primary call-to-action (CTA) is the button that performs the search, once address appear the primary path is accessed by selecting an address, what restrictions do you think exist on the colour of the button? Should it be the colour of the primary search button or a different colour? Or should it be a button at all?

The example includes a few ideas I've been mulling.

[image: Select Buttons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great start @UXfrom12. If your users are savvy enough, I would advise NOT having an action column with GO buttons. How about just allow a Green Mouseover for each Row? This way, the color Green is always related to a "forward progression" action.

[image]

Comment: I like this, I'm just ducking out of the office, but will read all the answers fully when I get home.

Comment: I'm home, I guess my only concern is, as ubiquitous as Google is, there's no distinct action to select an address. Although the answer is like Google, our site isn't Google, are there enough positive indicators to say 'mouse over and address and click to select it,' it seems strange, but in our user testing, there's possibly people who would just keep clicking the 'SEARCH' button. They may have moved on in the end, but I like guiding users as much as possible, hence the buttons on my wireframe.

Comment: Mouseovers only work if you're not allowed to use the app from anything other than a desktop with a mouse. Eg. no touch screens, no tablets, no mobile, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the width works the way you have it now. In fact, you have all actions in a column. That will grow familiar for users fast.
2. The button can be green if you make green your primary action color. It is smaller in hierarchy in comparison to the search button based on size.

**Suggestion**

Maybe you can disable (change color to grey) the search button after the search until the user changes his search query. This way the user attention will move to the remaining action buttons below it.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove the 'inline CTA'

Since this is a search drop down field users won't expect it to have a 'inline CTA' because the majority of dropdown components do not have it.

Take a look at Google, they do not have a this secondary CTA either and are the most visited site on the internet. Apparently, there is no problem of discarding it because the biggest site on the internet is working fine without it.
[image]

To conclude, because Google and dropdown components which are widely spread **users have formed a mental model which does not include second CTA for dropdowns**.
So, the only thing you can achieve with that is to confuse them.

Comment: The way I would describe it is a permanent drop-down with scroll. The reason I say this, and it's something that came out of user testing, standard drop-downs tend to disappear if you click outside of the field, this was a blocker for a number of our testers, so we decided that the proposed field would be a list with scroll, hence the buttons.

Comment: @UXfrom12 Then you're talking about a list, not a permanent dropdown. ;)